# How to use nested metafunctions in Boost.MPL?

Tags: c++, boost, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming, boost-mpl

I have a simple metafunction:

```
template <typename T>
using is_const_lvalue_reference = mpl::and_<
    std::is_lvalue_reference<T>,
    std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>
>;
```

Apparently, it doesn't work if `T` is an MPL placeholder because `remove_reference` is evaluated for the placeholder class instead of the substituted type. How to do this correctly to be able to use this metafunction in MPL algorithms?

UPDATE: The suggested solution was to replace the alias with a struct, which will delay the template instantiation in `std::remove_reference`. The question is, how to delay the instantiation inline, not using any helper structs?

```
template <typename Sequence>
using are_const_lvalue_references = mpl::fold<
    Sequence,
    mpl::true_,
    mpl::and_<
        mpl::_1,
        mpl::and_<
            std::is_lvalue_reference<mpl::_2>,
            std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<mpl::_2>::type>
        >
    >
>;
```

This example will apparently fail for the same reason. What should I change to make it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work to write type traits as aliases in this way because they get instantiated immediately. `is_const_lvalue_reference<_1>` is exactly `mpl::and_<std::is_lvalue_reference<_1>, std::is_const<_1>>` (since `_1` isn't a reference type) - that's always `false` since lvalue references aren't `const`. Pretty tricky way to write `false_` though!

Instead, you have to delay instantiation. Just make your type trait inherit from `mpl::and_` instead of aliasing it:

```
template <class T>
struct is_const_lvalue_reference
    : mpl::and_<
        std::is_lvalue_reference<T>,
        std::is_const<std::remove_reference_t<T>>
        >
{ };
```

This way, `std::remove_reference_t<T>` won't get instantiated unless we actually try to access `is_const_lvalue_reference<T>::type` - which won't happen until the `_1` gets substituted for the real type in `apply`.

---

Alternatively, since `apply<>` will invoke `::type` where it finds placeholders, you can just drop the explicit invocation of `::type` yourself. So this works:

```
BOOST_MPL_ASSERT(( mpl::apply<
    std::is_const<std::remove_reference<_1>>,
    int const&
    > ));
```

or with the original expression:

```
BOOST_MPL_ASSERT(( mpl::apply<
    mpl::and_<
        std::is_lvalue_reference<_1>,
        std::is_const<std::remove_reference<_1>>
    >,
    int const&
    > ));
```

Note that this construction doesn't work as a type trait though.

Comment: Thanks, it works this way, but if I ditch the struct and just use the expression in-place (inside a bigger MPL expression), I still get the same problem. How should I deal with that?

Comment: @lizarisk I don't know what that means. Perhaps ask a new question with specifics?

Comment: I mean, I understood that transforming an alias to a struct delays the template instantiation and solves the problem, but what if I just want use the expression inline (i.e. `remove_reference` in this case)? How should I delay template instantiation?

Comment: @lizarisk Updated.

Comment: Thanks! I dropped this solution because I was trying to use this both as type traits and as a part of a placeholder expression, and that got me confused for some reason.